# UI row alignment issue

Tags: python, interface

I have a bit of an issue keeping the checkboxes always on the right, when toggling some values on and off -

[image]

```
    def draw_item(self, _context, layout, _data, item, icon, active_data,
              _active_propname, index, flt_flag):

    key_block = item
    if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
        split = layout.split(factor=0.7, align=True)

        split.prop(
            key_block, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon)
        row = split.row(align=True)

        if _context.object.shape_show_value:
            row.prop(key_block, "value", text="", emboss=False)

        row.prop(key_block, "mute", text="", emboss=False)
```

Thank you Karan for the solution -

[image]

While this is doing what I was after the names seem to be cropped for some reason, so I'm sticking with a less elegant solution of wrapping 2 factor values inside conditional statement for now.

[image]

Comment: Using a less than elegant solution I put the whole layout inside an if statement for now, basically having 2 factor values. I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Try, `row.alignment='RIGHT'` before `row.prop(key_block, "mute", text="", emboss=False)`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what I was after. Oddly, this is cropping the name of my shapekeys in the list irregardless if the values are showed or not, so I may just go with the different factors depending in it's state for this one.

Good to know about the alignment option. Still need to warm up to the API docs.